# Закрыть встроенный javascript в noindex wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Не спрашивайте зачем, сам не знаю. Но сео-специалист закомандовал все встроеные скрипты, типа

```
<script>blablabla</script>
```

закрыть в noindex.
Т.к. на сайте используется очень много плагинов со своими скриптами (в т.ч. элементор) - руками будет каждый перебирать очень долго.
Может есть идеи ка это провернуть просто и быстро?

UPD - Не правильно понял. Нужно убрать описания JavaScript конструкций из кода страниц, т.е. комментарии которые в исходном коде отображаюся

```
   /* <![CDATA[ */ <script>blablabla</script> /* ]]> */
```

Comment: Тогда отсутствие скриптов сломает сайт и он станет хуже индексироваться в поисковиках. Очень настойчиво поспрашивайте у вашего сео-специалиста, зачем это нужно

Comment: Не правильно понял задачу
Нужно убрать описания JavaScript конструкций из кода страниц, т.е. комментарии
Которые в исходном коде отображаюся /* <![CDATA[ */

Comment: гони такого сеошника поганой метлой

Comment: Эм, а комментарии-то тем более зачем убирать? Если они действительно комментарии — значит они не влияют вообще абсолютно ни на что (разве что трафик чутка кушают, но это мелочи)

Comment: Так я и не говорю убрать их из кода, убрать их только из исходного кода который уже скомпилировался для браузера только.

Comment: А что это даст?

Comment: Вопрос снят, всем спасиб.
Совсем забіл о плагине Autoptimize :)